# How to find a string in text and return the string from text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need find a string which already has special chars removed. So, I want to do is to find that string in a sentence and return the string with special chars.
Ex: `string = France09`

`Sentence : i leaved in France'09.`

now I did `re.search('France09',sentence)`, it will return `True` or `False`. But I want to get the output as `France'09`.

Can any one help me.

Comment: Your regex is correct if the expected output only `France'09`. You may need `group()` to extract the output.

Comment: So you want to have the `'`s added to your results? Do the words that are expected to have a `'` follow a specific pattern? Are they always a word followed by a number? Otherwise, how will you know where to put the `'`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), search is *not* returning `True` or `False`:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/18NJ2E/1

TL;DR

```py
import re

regex = r"(?P<relevant_info>France'09)"
test_str = "Sentence : i leaved in France'09."
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group('relevant_info'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Input_str = "i leaved in France'09"

Word_list = Input_str.split(" ")
for val in Word_list:
    if not val.isalnum():
        print(val)
```

Output:

```
France'09
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a regular expression that matches the special characters at any location:

```
import re
Sentence = "i leaved in France'09"
Match = 'France09'
Match2 = "[']*".join(Match)
m = re.search(Match2, Sentence)
print(m.group(0))
```

Match2 gets the value `"F[']*r[']*a[']*n[']*c[']*e[']*0[']*9"`. You can add other special characters into the `[']` part.

Comment: can you show me how can u handle it for two special char's?
sentence='I was born on 12/31/1989'
field='12311989

Comment: @yoganand_DS Update Sentence and Match variables. `Match2 = ['/]*".join(Match)`